# Magento 2 CMS block names in dropdown

Tags: magento2, adminform

I want to display CMS block names (for example, footer links, promotional banners, etc.) and display modes (for example, products only, static block only, static block and products) in the admin form dropdown.

In Magento 1, I have displayed it using the following code:

#### Display mode:

```
'values'=>Mage::getModel('catalog/category_attribute_source_mode')->getAllOptions() display mode
```

#### CMS block

```
'values' => Mage::getModel('catalog/category_attribute_source_page')->getAllOptions()
```

What is the equivalent code for the above in Magento 2 for getting the CMS block name and display modes in the admin form dropdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Magento2,** also have the source Model for an eav attribute  concept like Magento 1.X.

So, you can get **display mod and static block** using respective **source model**

***Display Mode, you can use***
[**`Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Mode`**](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Category/Attribute/Source/Mode.php#L13)

***Cms static block, you can use***

and [**`Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Page`**](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Category/Attribute/Source/Page.php#L15)

**On  `__construct()` function you need to inject this two classes**

```
protected $mode; 
    protected $Staticblocks; 

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Mode $mode,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Page $Staticblocks,

    ) {
    ...
        $this->mode = $mode;
        $this->Staticblocks = $Staticblocks;

        .....
    }
```

Then at your code, you can get  option values & label by

- *`$this->mode->getAllOptions();`*
- *`$this->Staticblocks->getAllOptions();`*

Comment: How can I call this in form once I injected the constructor.Thanks in advance.

Comment: See the  update..you can understand